# Migrate chrome app to chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

With google announcing the eventual cancellation of chrome apps, we're looking at options. Electron and ilk are interesting but we would sorely miss the distribution that google provides and we'd rather consider the possibility of presenting our interface through a chrome extension.

I think a popup is a poor place to locate the app so Im hoping that i can open a tab and host the app in it. I don't want to fetch application files from a web server, I'd rather have it bundled with the extension. I also need freedom from CORS.

Is this (reasonably) possible?

Comment: Depends on what apis you need.

Comment: I suggest reading the [differences and similiarties between Apps and Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/apps_vs_extensions) in the docs. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @noogui , yes, I've built chrome apps and extensions before. I know that extensions generally have very light UI (popups) and mostly geared for extending existing web pages downloaded from the web. But since they are planning to cancel chrome apps, I'm looking for "a way" that I can distribute my app via an extension that doesn't involve hosting it on a web server. I know I can open tabs but the means of communication I'm familiar with is very simple messaging and, I think might be difficult to manage a UI and even port my existing app.

Comment: In [Chromium blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html), you are encouraged to move to the Web, that is [Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) because they say it can do what Chrome Apps can do, even the offline functionality thanks to service workers. There are always decisions to be made. Either use Electron or move to the Web.

Comment: Thanks @noogui, your comments have led me to realize that I'm probably flogging a dead horse and Google is pushing towards Progressive Web Apps and if we don't like it then we can use Electron or something else.
I also realized that this question cannot be objectively answered (although your comments helped me reach a conclusion) so it is probably a poor question for the format of stackoverflow... apologies...